# User does not have permission to run DBCC DBREINDEX

Tags: sql-server-2005, security

I get the following error message in SQL Server 2005:

```
User '<username>' does not have permission to run DBCC DBREINDEX for object '<table>'.
```

Which minimum role do I have to give to user in order to run the command?

Comment: Cheers, adding db_owner worked :)

Comment: db_owner is not the minimum privileged role.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to be a member of the **db_ddladmin** or the **db_owner** role AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

> Caller must own the table, or be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role, the db_owner fixed database role, or the db_ddladmin fixed database role.

[DBCC DBREINDEX (Transact-SQL) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181671(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON Tablename TO [domain\username]

Comment: Note: this does change the ownership of the table.